# Writing and naming multiple files in python

Tags: python

The following code writes multiple files with certain number of lines from "t.txt" and name each file with the increasing line count. Now I want to write all files with name "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8..." or "mya, myb, myc, myd...". How do I change the code?

```
  9 with open ("t.txt") as f:
 10     probelist = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
 11     for i in probelist:
 12         if not itemcount % filesize:
 13             outfile = open("{}".format(filenum).zfill(8), "w")
 14         filenum += 1
 15         outfile.write(i+"\n")
 16         itemcount += 1
 17     outfile.close()
```

Comment: what is filesize and what do you mean by *get*? Also why read all the lines into a list, strip the newlines and then put it back on?

Comment: Actually I am dividing a large file into small files. I first put each line of a big file (t.txt) into a list and strip the white spaces and then write every 10000 lines (filesize) in to a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.islice` to get `filesize` slice using `enumerate` to get get a unique name for each file, passing `1` as the start to enumerate to start the indexing at `1`:

```
from itertools import islice
with open("t.txt") as f:
    for ind, sli in enumerate(iter(lambda:list(islice(f,filesize)),[]),1):
        with open("{}.txt".format(ind),"w") as out:
            out.writelines(sli)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added "file_count" to do what I assumed "filenum" was doing.  Does this do the job for you?  Sorry about the earlier confusion; I was paying attention to the variable name instead of the definition.

```
file_count = 1
with open ("t.txt") as f:
    probelist = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
    for i in probelist:
        if not itemcount % filesize:
            file_name = str(file_count) + ".txt"
            outfile = open(file_name, "w")
            file_count += 1
        filenum += 1
        outfile.write(i+"\n")
        itemcount += 1
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: filenum is the accumulated line numbers. Each file contains 10000 lines so they are named 10000.txt, 20000.txt, 30000.txt... What I want is name the file as 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt... or a.txt, b.txt, c.txt...

Comment: So go ahead and give them those names.  filename = filenum + ".txt"

Comment: I have 10000 files. As I said filenum is accumulated line count and I don't want use it as my file names. My original code is naming files in this way.

Comment: No worries. I should have defined my variables clearly. It makes sense when you add a file count variable. I'm trying it.